# AC/DC vs conventional/electron flow current

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

Conventional current is from positive to negative and electron flow is from negative to positive. 
If we go with conventional current sign, would it be right to say DC current is always as per the conventional current and AC current switches between conventional and actual electron flow? Or these two directions are completely different and I am using it incorrectly.

Comment: From what I understand you flip the positive and negative terminals(back and forth) in AC so we still use "conventional current" It's just that the entire +/- sides have now swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both DC and AC can be described from the viewpoint of the conventional current direction. The only difference is that for AC the direction changes all the time. But as it changes, so does the electron flow direction change. So is *still* opposite to the conventional current.

In fact it is the *polarity* of what drives the current, that changes all the time.

- In DC, you have a fixed polarity. Like attaching a battery. Positive potential at one end, let's call it A, negative at the other, let's call it B. Current flows from positive to negative potential, so from A to B. This is the conventional definition. For metallic wires and component, electrons are charge-carriers and they move oppositely, from B to A.
- In AC, you have a varying polarity. Like constantly flipping the battery over.

  - You start out with positive potential at A and negative at B, in which case current flows from positive to negative, from A to B. Electrons flow oppositely, from B to A.
  - But in the next instant you flip the polarity and have *negative* at A and *positive* at B. But current still flows from positive to negative as always, so from B to A. And electrons flow from A to B now now that the polarity flipped. *Everything* flipped when the polarity flipped. The conventional current direction is **still** and **always** opposite to the electron flow direction, because they **both flip**.

And it will always be like this. Because **conventional current** is defined as if the current was a **positive charge-carrier**. So it will *always* be opposite to the electron flow direction, because that is based on the **negative** electron charge-carrier.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not true. Conventional current is **always** from possitive to negative, whereas the electron flow is from negative to possitive, always against current.

In short:

- Possitive charges move in the same direction as $I$.
- Negative charges move in the opposite direction of $I$.

In circuits you have electrons, and they **always** go "against" the current vector.

In AC current, the $I$ arrow is changing direction.
The electron flux is also changing direction, with the same ferquency, but the changes are the opopsite, so that you always have

$I\rightarrow; \qquad \Phi_e \leftarrow$

or

$I\leftarrow; \qquad \Phi_e \rightarrow$

Where $I$ is the intensity of current and $\Phi_e$ is the electron flux.

Answer (score 1):

> If we go with conventional current sign, would it be right to say DC current is always as per the conventional current and AC current switches between conventional and actual electron flow?

Not quite.  For currents in metal the charge carriers are negative, $\rho<0$.  Since the current density is $\mathbf J= \rho \mathbf v$ that means that the current is always in the opposite direction as $\mathbf v$.

In AC circuits when the charges are moving in the positive direction then the current is in the negative direction, and when the charges are moving in the negative direction then the current is in the positive direction.  The conventional current is always opposite the direction of the electron movement.

Note, in electrolytes and some other situations the charge carriers may be positive. In those cases the current would be in the same direction as the motion of the charge carriers.  You can even have charge carriers with both signs, in which case the current would consist of motion of positive charges in one direction and negative charges in the other.  The electrical effects are almost* all based on the current so the sign of the charge carriers is usually irrelevant.

*The only exception that comes to mind is the Hall effect

Answer (score -2):

Years ago I was teaching electronics and I told my class that if you take any point in any circuit then electrons flow from negative to positive past that point. In an a.c. circuit current will flow first one way then the other dependant on the positive and negative voltage peaks of the applied sinusoidal voltage applied. Some time later I was told that science now said that electrons do not escape from their atoms nucleus but just move into wider orbits depending on the voltages applied. A.C or D.C. please check all of the above. I ain't no Professor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).